# tabIndex fails in an AS3 swf loaded into a flex app

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, tabindex

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here. I'm loading a AS3 swf containing a form (created by one of our designers) into a flex app. The swf's tabIndex properties work fine when the swf is viewed by itself, however, once it's loaded into the flex app:

```
<mx:SWFLoader source="form.swf" top="20" horizontalCenter="0" id="formSwf" complete="swfCompleteHandler(event)"/>
```

the form fields stop receiving focus on tab. I've been looking at the FocusManager in flex, for some sort of solution, but I can't seem to find any examples, and I'm not entirely sure I'm looking in the right place. Am I stuck redoing this form in flex?

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to close down for the day, so this is off the cuff without any research - sorry.

I think what you need to do is set your SWFLoader's `tabEnabled` property to `false` and set its `tabChildren` property to `true`.

Comment: You'd think this would work, but it doesn't seem to. I wonder if this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is not spam. http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg111610.html